# Reset inputSwicth PrimeNg when click on cancel button of the confirmation dialog pop up

Tags: angular, toggle, primeng, togglebutton

I am using inputSwitch PrimeNg as a toggle with a confirmation modal.
My inputSwitch is unchecked and When I click on it, the modal is displayed, then I click on No, the inputSwitch still remains checked.
I don't know how to prevent it when i don't confirm the change.

HTML :

```
<p-inputSwitch [ngModel]="opportunity.mainQuoteId === quote.id" 
  (onChange)="onChangeMainQuote($event, opportunity, quote.id)"> 
</p-inputSwitch>
```

And TS :

```
onChangeMainQuote(event, opportunity: Opportunity, mainQuoteId: string) {
        this.confirmationDialogService.confirm('Changement de devis principal',
            'Etes-vous sur de vouloir changer de devis principal ?', 'LABEL_CONFIRM_DELETION', 'LABEL_CANCEL')
            .then((confirmed) => {
                if (confirmed) {
                    if (event.checked) {
                        opportunity.mainQuoteId = mainQuoteId;
                        this.cdr.detectChanges();
                    }                 
                }              
            })
            .catch((res) => {
            });
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest u use angular double binding.

html :

```
 <p-inputSwitch [ngModel]="opportunity.mainQuoteId === quote.id" 
    [(ngModel)]="isChecked"
      (onChange)="onChangeMainQuote($event, opportunity, quote.id)"> 
    </p-inputSwitch>
```

ts :

now when you click "no" just change the value of isChecked to false

Comment: I tried that, but on loading I have no way to initialize the value of isChecked.
So all the inout switches will be false on the first display of my table...

Comment: to be honest I don't exactly know where the problem is, it would be ideal if you can provide a stackblitz or codepen example